# How can I avoid nested tuple unpacking when enumerating zipped lists?

Tags: python, python-itertools, enumerate, iterable-unpacking

How can I avoid using nested tuple unpacking when enumerating a list of tuples like this?

```
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip("1234", "ABCD")):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: Did you know you can check a box on the 'Ask Question' form (called "Answer your own question") and put in the answer in one go?

Comment: What is wrong with that code?

Comment: @jamylak Nothing except at least for me it feels more awkward than the answer I just posted.

Comment: @lazyr I like the original more, no need to over complicate it

Comment: @jamylak To each his own, I guess.

Comment: @Martijn No, I did not see that. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`itertools.count`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) to avoid nested tuple unpacking:

```
from itertools import count

for i, x, y in zip(count(), "1234", "ABCD"):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

That code is fine, and is the cleanest idiom.

Trying to avoid it is solving a non-problem, it's actually **worse** to use `itertools.count` than `enumerate`, because one pitfall is it breaks if we ever use `zip_longest`/ iterator lengths differ, since `count()` is an infinite iterator:

#### `itertools.count` works if we use `zip()`, i.e. both iterators are the same length, or we're ok with truncating the longer one to the length of the shorter one:

```
for i, x, y in itertools.zip_longest(count(), "1234", "ABCD"): print(f'{i}: {x} {y}')
```

#### `itertools.count` breaks (i.e. runs infinitely) if we use `izip_longest()`, iterators are different length:

```
for i, x, y in itertools.zip_longest(count(), "1234", "ABCDE"):
    print(f'{i}: {x} {y}')

0: 1 A
1: 2 B
2: 3 C
3: 4 D
4: None E
5: None None
6: None None
...
```

Since it would be very confusing to have one idiom for iterators of the same size, and another for different-length, we should not generally use `count()` for that. Even if you know your code won't, somebody may copy.modify your code and hit this. So it's bad idiom.